# Distance between one point and rest of the points in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing some code to calculate the real distance between one point and the rest of the points from the same array. The array holds positions of particles in 3D space. There is N-particles so the array's shape is `(N,3)`. I choose one particle and calculate the distance between this particle and the rest of the particles, all within one array.

Would anyone here have any idea how to do this?

What I have so far:

```
xbox = 10
ybox = 10
zbox = 10
nparticles =15
positions = np.empty([nparticles, 3])
for i in range(nparticles):
     xrandomalocation = random.uniform(0, xbox)
     yrandomalocation = random.uniform(0, ybox)
     zrandomalocation = random.uniform(0, zbox)
     positions[i, 0] = xrandomalocation
     positions[i, 1] = yrandomalocation
     positions[i, 2] = zrandomalocation
```

And that's pretty much all I have right now. I was thinking of using `np.linalg.norm` however I am not sure at all how to implement it to my code (or maybe use it in a loop)?

Comment: can you put some code which you've tried ? atleast the array ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31485068/5267751) (first line in the question) help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses. In your case posting a sample array and expected output would be useful.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @user202729 I have added what I have now.

Comment: @Isma I have added some parts of the code :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you could use [`scipy.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) or [`scipy.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) for this. For example, to get the distances from point `X` to the points in `coords`:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance
>>> X = [(35.0456, -85.2672)]
>>> coords = [(35.1174, -89.9711),
...           (35.9728, -83.9422),
...           (36.1667, -86.7833)]
>>> distance.cdist(X, coords, 'euclidean')
array([[ 4.70444794,  1.6171966 ,  1.88558331]])
```

`pdist` is similar, but only takes one array, and you get the distances between all pairs.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this function:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def closest_node(node, nodes):
    closest = distance.cdist([node], nodes)
    index = closest.argmin()
    euclidean = closest[0]
    return nodes[index], euclidean[index]
```

where *node* is the single point in the space you want to compare with an array of points called *nodes*. it returns the point and the euclidean distance to your original *node*